# presto how to turn array to array of maps with fixed keys

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Let’s say I have a column of array type, eg, [1,2,3,4]. I would like to turn it to something like `[{‘id’:1}, {‘id’:2}, {‘id’:3}, {‘id’:4}]`. So technically with dup keys. Is this possible?

I trid with MAP, but failed with dup keys warning

Answer (score 0):

`map` will create a single map, you need to transform your array of integers to array of maps, so use [`transform`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (arr) AS (
    values (array[1,2,3,4])
)

-- query
SELECT transform(arr, i -> map(array['id'], array[i]))
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

```
              _col0               
----------------------------------
 [{id=1}, {id=2}, {id=3}, {id=4}]
```